# ActiveRecord conditional query with nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model with the following nested structure:

```
#<Model id: 2, list_name: "Freddo", extra_data: {"users_count"=>2000}>
```

I would like to perform a query to return all records based on a condition where users_count > 1000. Such that:

```
Model.where("extra_data.users_count > 1000")
```

Now the above code would probably work if it was a nested array, but when it's wrapped in curly braces how can I access this?

Comment: Can you share the schema details @ugotchi?

Comment: what is type of extra_data column?

Comment: If you're likely to have a lot of cases like this, it may be better to have `extra_data` be a separate table you can join to, so you can query it like this: `Model.joins(:extra_data).where("extra_data.name = 'users_count' AND extra_data.value > 1000")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that `extra_data` as a JSONB or JSON column, you can do something like below

`Model.where("CAST(extra_data ->> 'users_count' AS NUMERIC) > ?", 1000)`

Postgres JSON operator `->>` will return the result in the form of text and converting the value as an integer and compare with the value.

Reference - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb

Comment: Do we have the similar one for mysql 5.7?

Comment: Hope this will help - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html